# Get last n rows idxmin for each group by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

## Goal

I want to get the index of the min of last 3 rows based on `low` column.

```
     date   hy_code low
0   1990/12/19  A   95.79
1   1990/12/20  A   99.98
2   1990/12/21  A   103.73
3   1990/12/24  A   109.13
4   1990/12/25  A   114.55
5   1990/12/26  A   120.25
6   1990/12/27  A   125.27
7   1990/12/28  A   125.28
8   1990/12/31  A   126.48
9   1991/1/2    A   127.61
10  1990/12/19  B   95.79
11  1990/12/20  B   99.98
12  1990/12/21  B   103.73
13  1990/12/24  B   109.13
14  1990/12/25  B   114.55
15  1990/12/26  B   120.25
16  1990/12/27  B   125.27
17  1990/12/28  B   125.28
18  1990/12/31  B   126.48
19  1991/1/2    B   127.61
```

## Try

```
df.assign(l1m_lowest_idx=df.rolling(3)['low'].agg(lambda x:x.idxmin()))
```

It runs slow when data become large.

Comment: Other than the speed, does your "try" do what you want it to?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can tell, your "try" does indeed do what you describe: an index-of-rolling-minimum. You're also correct to identify that it has efficiency issues; whenever a `lambda` appears in Pandas that spells trouble.

Unfortunately, I don't see a good, built-in way to do this in Pandas. What I'm going to suggest is that you drop down to Numpy, which should be able to do this efficiently:

- Create a padded array where the first few values are equal to the first value of `low`
- Use `sliding_window_view` to get your rolling effect, vectorised over a two-dimensional array
- Apply a vectorised `argmin` over one axis

Also take care to have the output column be integer-typed, which it was not.

### What you're "actually doing"

A word of caution: what you're doing currently probably doesn't make sense. Your sliding window steamrolls over a `hy_code` boundary with a chronological discontinuity. I would expect `date` and `hy_code` to form a multi-index, and for your rolling min to respect that, which it doesn't. I have not shown how to handle this.

### Suggested

In practice this would look like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('273660.csv')

n = len(df)
WINDOW = 3
padded = np.empty(n + WINDOW - 1)
padded[WINDOW:] = df.low.values[1:]

# Rather than NaN for the partial-window start, just fill with the first value
padded[:WINDOW] = df.low.values[0]

# Will be of shape n x WINDOW, each row shifting over by one more index
slid = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(padded, window_shape=WINDOW)

# Get minimum indices within each window, and then convert from a relative
# offset to an absolute offset
min_offsets = np.argmin(slid, axis=1) + np.arange(n) - WINDOW + 1

# Rather than NaN for the starting values, apply the minimum to the partial window.
# This requires a piecewise operation on the first few indices; otherwise they'll
# be negative.
min_offsets[:WINDOW] = np.clip(min_offsets[:WINDOW], a_min=0, a_max=None)
df['l1m_lowest_idx'] = min_offsets
print(df)
```

### Output

```
          date hy_code     low  l1m_lowest_idx
0   1990/12/19       A   95.79               0
1   1990/12/20       A   99.98               0
2   1990/12/21       A  103.73               0
3   1990/12/24       A  109.13               1
4   1990/12/25       A  114.55               2
5   1990/12/26       A  120.25               3
6   1990/12/27       A  125.27               4
7   1990/12/28       A  125.28               5
8   1990/12/31       A  126.48               6
9     1991/1/2       A  127.61               7
10  1990/12/19       B   95.79              10
11  1990/12/20       B   99.98              10
12  1990/12/21       B  103.73              10
13  1990/12/24       B  109.13              11
14  1990/12/25       B  114.55              12
15  1990/12/26       B  120.25              13
16  1990/12/27       B  125.27              14
17  1990/12/28       B  125.28              15
18  1990/12/31       B  126.48              16
19    1991/1/2       B  127.61              17
```

Comment: Very nice. With 10K rows on my machine, striding takes 219 µs ± 28.8 µs while rolling takes 826 ms ± 49.8 ms.

Comment: @Reinderien I wanna keep np.nan so just not run  padded[:WINDOW] = df.low.values[0]?

Comment: What is the motivation for keeping NaN? If the very first output value considers a window size of one, is the minimum of that window not the first element?